# Images appear in simulators on Xcode but not on device

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am making an app in swift that has a central map (UIViewController) with multiple levels you can click into (each represented by an identical image of a flag). These levels are greyed out until they are unlocked and then become accessible and change color. On the iOS simulator, all flags appear on the map and everything works. On the iPhone, however, after the first 3 levels, half the flags disappear and never come back. Here is the function that places all the level images:

```
  func createButton(tag:Int, widthRatio:Double, heightRatio:Double, completed:Bool){
    let buttonLevel = UIButton(type: .custom)
    buttonLevel.tag = tag
    buttonLevel.frame.size = CGSize(width: Double(buttonWidth), height: Double(buttonHeight))
    buttonLevel.center = CGPoint(x: Double(screenSize.width)*widthRatio, y: Double(contentView.frame.height)*heightRatio)
    buttonLevel.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5*buttonLevel.bounds.size.width
    buttonLevel.clipsToBounds = true
    print("Completed: \(completed)")

    if(completed){
        buttonLevel.setImage(UIImage(named:"level\(tag)blue"), for: .normal)
        //buttonLevel.layer.borderWidth = 1
        //buttonLevel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    } else {
        buttonLevel.setImage(UIImage(named:"level\(tag)red"), for: .normal)
        buttonLevel.isEnabled = false;
    }

    buttonLevel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for:.touchUpInside)
    contentView.addSubview(buttonLevel)
    buttonLevel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

I have already made sure the images are in the bundle resources, changed them from png to jpg and tried adding them to the assets folder or the root, to no avail.

Comment: Show more context please. Content view of what? Is this a table view? Then show all the table view data source code, as it is likely that the problem is there. Show enough code to allow reproduction of the phenomenon. Do not assume you know where the problem is; after all, if you knew that, you’d probably have solved the problem already.